# Which workflow to get polygons from a geographic area and a raster file?

Tags: d3.js, gdal, shapefile, topojson, ogr

**Given a TIFF file corresponding to Europe, and converted into shape contours :**

```
gdal_contour -a elev Europe_input.tif Europe_output.shp -fl -1000 -500 -200 -50 0 50 100 200 500 1000 2000 4000 6000
```

**Given defined area corresponting to France :**

```
West : 005° 48' W
East : 010° E
North : 051° 30' N
South : 041° N
```

**How to get only the features whose geometry intersects my defined area with gdal ?**

Comment: I don't believe the ogr2ogr utility or any of the other gdal utilities supports polygon intersection checks, although the GDAL libraries do.  You may have to write some code, use a spatial DB, or if it's a one-time thing, use your favorite GIS editor.

Comment: It's for a script project, there is all the fun :]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Clip the raster](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/FAQRaster#HowdoIusegdal_translatetoextractorclipasub-sectionofaraster) to the area of interest with [gdal_translate](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html), e.g.:

```
gdal_translate -projwin ulx uly lrx lry Europe_input.tif Europe_subregion.tif
```

where `ulx uly lrx lry` is the upper/lower x/y bounds of the area of interest in the units of `Europe_input.tif` (maybe metres, maybe arcseconds, maybe degrees, I can't tell). After clipping the raster, then process `Europe_subregion.tif` with `gdal_contour` using the commands in your question.

Comment: I edited your answer. But what is `src_dataset`? Could we just write `gdal_translate -projwin ulx uly lrx lry Europe_input.tif Europe_subregion.tif` ?

Comment: Oh I see, yeah src_dataset was a typo, all fixed now.

Comment: After test : Accepted !